# Background turns white instead of transparent (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css

Hi so I've been working on this all day and can't seem to find the solution to turn the background colour transparent (to match the article background). Would appreciate any help. At the moment the background is set to blue. Will attach the code for reference. I've also used php (please dont tell me to use otherwise as php is compulsory for this)

```css
article{
    height: 540px;
    background: url("assets/images/brick.png");
}
.navbar-collapse{
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    color: #F1654A;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #000, 2px -2px 0 #000, -2px 2px 0 #000, 2px 2px 0 #000;
    font-family: "Cooper Black", serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CCDBD8 ;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #000, 2px -2px 0 #000, -2px 2px 0 #000, 2px 2px 0 #000;
}

.navbar-light{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #2e90b9, #268fbb, #1d8dbe, #128cc0, #038ac2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 7px 15px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 7px 15px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 1px 7px 15px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);

}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: #CCDBD8;
}
```

```html
<body>

<!--Nav Bar using Bootstrap-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light ">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-left"><img src="assets/images/bblogo2.png" alt="logo"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#menu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id ="menu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="<?php if($page=='home'){echo 'active';}?>">
        <a href="index.php" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    </li>
        <li class="<?php if($page=='top scores'){echo 'active';}?>">
            <a href="topscores.php" class="nav-link">Top Scores</a>
        </li>
        <li class="<?php if($page=='game'){echo 'active';}?>">
            <a href="game.php" class="nav-link">Game</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>


</nav>

</body>
```

Comment: I take it you mean you are setting `.navbar` to blue here. If set it to `transparent`, it appears white because the body is white.

Comment: Howdy, welcome to SO! Not entirely sure what you're asking for. Make what transparent? The navbar that has `bg-light` specified orrrrrr something else?

Comment: I need the navbar transparent (to see the current picture) I tried giving the body the same image the article has but the nav bar still comes white!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your background css for the navbar-light class with background-color and set it to transparent.

```
.navbar-light{
   background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 7px 15px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 7px 15px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 1px 7px 15px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);

}
```

You'll see a white background because the body is white.

Comment: I tried giving the body the image that the article has at the moment but the nav bar still comes white...

Comment: and did you give the navbar a fixed property so it sits over the article body?